# PHP :multiple file upload count issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to upload multiple files in my CodeIgniter project using below code

```
  <form action="<?= base_url('admin/dashboard/fileUpload') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="files[]"   multiple style="display: block;width: 100%;"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="count" value=""  id="count"/>
      <input type='submit' class=' btn btn-primary'  value='Submit'/>
                
 </form> 


<script>
    $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
            var fileCount = this.files.length;
            $('#count').val(fileCount);
            console.log(fileCount);
        })
</script>
```

**Controller code**

```
public function fileUpload(){
        
        if($this->input->post()){
            $path=  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/folders/files/';
            $countfiles = $this->input->post('count');
             for($i=$countfiles;$i>=0;$i--){
               $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
               move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$path.$filename);
                $this->db->insert('folder_files',array(
                     'file_link'     =>$filename
                ));
             }
             $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','files are added');
             redirect('admin/dashboard/files/');
             
        }
        
    }
```

Now the problem with this code is that it runs up to 20 iterations and then it gives error undefined index error here `$filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];`  i tried to `print_r($_FILES)`  that also has 20 files starting form 0-19.

Could someone please help me to sort out the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please use `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because when you count files in Javascript, it starts from 1, but in PHP code index in `$_FILES` starts from 0. So it looks like when you upload 20 files, PHP tries to execute loop 21 times

What I would suggest:

1. Change loop in PHP by removing `=` sign.

```
for($i=$countfiles;$i>0;$i--){
```

2. When you accessing data in `$_FILES` array, adjust index by -1. For example, `$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]` becomes `$_FILES['files']['name'][$i-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i=>$filename) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$path.$filename);
    $this->db->insert('folder_files',array(
        'file_link'=>$filename
    ));
}
```